# Chrombook with Ubuntu Mate 16.04 Lts have keyboard problem.

Tags: keyboard, chromebook

I have installed Ubuntu Mate 16.04 Lts 32bit on my Toshiba Chromebook. The keys on the top wont work as they should. Arrows, light up and down, sound key wont work. I can't fint out how to change it. On a Chromebook there is no F keys, I guess this is the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make media keys work on a Chromebook natively running Ubuntu MATE 22.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1451097/how-to-make-media-keys-work-on-a-chromebook-natively-running-ubuntu-mate-22-04)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** I was curious and spent more time trying to bring up support for this layout in Ubuntu 18.04. There is a repository which mostly consists of one [patch](https://github.com/GalliumOS/xkeyboard-config/blob/master/debian/patches/chromebook.patch) against the Ubuntu packages. I decided to download the latest package of `xkeyboard-config` from [here](http://apt.galliumos.org/pool/main/x/xkeyboard-config/) which worked as expected for XFCE/Xubuntu. The Chromebook layouts can be selected from the layout list. It gets more difficult getting it to work with Gnome. I tried adding `'chromebook_m:overlay'` to `/org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/xkb-options` in dconf after reading [this](https://www.beatworm.co.uk/blog/keyboards/gnome-wayland-xkb) and [this](https://www.blaenkdenum.com/posts/custom-xkb-options-with-gnome/) but it did not work. Setting `XKBMODEL="chromebook_m"` in `/etc/default/keyboard` [worked](https://www.reddit.com/r/GalliumOS/comments/5ewhk1/keyboard_overlay_options_in_gnome_shell/dafpyv3/), but not in Gnome Wayland on 18.04. That's as far as I got. Gnome Wayland [should](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/309729/49853) work with XKB maps but I don't have much time to investigate further at the moment.

---

You need to configure a matching keyboard layout, the Ubuntu based Gallium OS comes with additional configuration files to make such keyboards work. I have not yet dug deeper into this problem and how they solved it but I think `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/chromebook` is where the configuration is stored, but you'd better try [Gallium OS](https://wiki.galliumos.org/Media_keys_and_default_keybindings) itself first.

```
// This mapping assumes that inet(evdev) will also be sourced
partial
xkb_symbols "overlay" {
    key <LWIN> { [ Overlay1_Enable ], overlay1=<LWIN> };
    key <I225> { [ Overlay1_Enable ], overlay1=<I225> };

    key <AB09> { overlay1=<INS> };

    key <LEFT> { overlay1=<HOME> };
    key <RGHT> { overlay1=<END> };
    key <UP>   { overlay1=<PGUP> };
    key <DOWN> { overlay1=<PGDN> };

    key <FK01> { overlay1=<I166> };
    key <FK02> { overlay1=<I167> };
    key <FK03> { overlay1=<I181> };
    key <FK04> { overlay1=<I160> };
    key <FK05> { overlay1=<I235> };
    key <FK06> { overlay1=<I232> }; // XF86MonBrightnessDown
    key <FK07> { overlay1=<I233> }; // XF86MonBrightnessUp
    key <FK08> { overlay1=<MUTE> };
    key <FK09> { overlay1=<VOL-> };
    key <FK10> { overlay1=<VOL+> };

    key <AE01> { overlay1=<FK01> };
    key <AE02> { overlay1=<FK02> };
    key <AE03> { overlay1=<FK03> };
    key <AE04> { overlay1=<FK04> };
    key <AE05> { overlay1=<FK05> };
    key <AE06> { overlay1=<FK06> };
    key <AE07> { overlay1=<FK07> };
    key <AE08> { overlay1=<FK08> };
    key <AE09> { overlay1=<FK09> };
    key <AE10> { overlay1=<I236> }; // KEY_KBDILLUMTOGGLE
    key <AE11> { overlay1=<I237> }; // KEY_KBDILLUMDOWN
    key <AE12> { overlay1=<I238> }; // KEY_KBDILLUMUP
    key <BKSP> { overlay1=<DELE> };

    key <LALT> { overlay1=<CAPS> };
    key <RALT> { overlay1=<CAPS> };

    // For some strange reason, some Super_R events are triggered when
    // the Search key is released (i.e. with overlay on).
    // This maps RWIN to a dummy key (<I253>), to make sure we catch it.
    key <RWIN> { [ NoSymbol ], overlay1=<I253> };

    // Map dummy key to no symbol
    key <I253> { [ NoSymbol ] };
};
```